# Who’s the artist who did the illustrations in the beginning of Little Shop of Horrors?

Tags: credits, little-shop-of-horrors

Who's the artist who did the work on *Little Shop of Horrors* (1960) here:

http://annyas.com/screenshots/updates/little-shop-of-horrors-1960-roger-corman/

It seems they didn’t credit movies back then very well.  I was curious if anyone knew who the artist was.

Comment: I think I disagree with the VtC (although I'm biased, as an answer-er) as this is asking about the title art of a film, which is part of the production. I'm sure we've had questions about the James Bond down-the-gun-barrel art here before.

Answer (score 1):

We'll never know, unless someone actually contacts [Daniel Haller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Haller) quickly (he's 93). Assuming he'll tell you, that is. Looking at the web site [The Art of the Title](https://www.artofthetitle.com/title/the-little-shop-of-horrors/) which is specifically about Title Art of Motion Pictures, that movie's title art is un-credited.

Oh, and the movie's credits were unusual for movies (even B-movies). The fact was that Roger Corman thought the movie would tank, even compared to other B-movies, so much so that he didn't copyright it. LSoH is in the Public Domain, so any aspiring film-makers want to make another one?

Comment: Re yours at sentence; I was unfamiliar with this version of the film (only the Rick Moranis one) so looked it up on IMDb. There I found a new version is in production starring Taron Egarton, Chris Evans and Scarlett Johannsen.